# ARIA role of list social media links

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm trying to improve the accessibility of a site, but I don't know how to label the list of social media links in the footer. These links lead to my accounts on facecook, twitter, etc. I do not want to label these links with `role="navigation"`, because they aren't used to navigate the site.

This is a fairly common design pattern, but I can't seem to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The role I would apply to the whole footer is '[contentInfo](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#contentinfo)':

> Examples of information included in this region of the page are copyrights and links to privacy statements.
>
> User agents SHOULD treat elements with the role of contentinfo as navigational landmarks.

So it is about the (main) content, but not part of it, and treated (potentially) as a type of navigation. The `contentInfo` footer could also contain other links, which would be fine.

Comment: Yeah this is what I've done. The footer contains a repetition of the header nav which I marked as navigation and I added aria-label="social media link" to the relevant list.

Comment: Great, can you tick as 'answered' then?

Answer (score 0):

Using the role `contentInfo` is a good option, but [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Contentinfo_role), the `footer` element is better.

Comment: They are essentially the same.  The `<footer>` element is an HTML **element** just like `<header>`, `<table>`, or `<ul>`.  `contentinfo` is a *value* for the **role attribute**.  It is not an an element.  The default **role** of a `<footer>` is (usually) `contentinfo`.  See https://w3c.github.io/html-aria/#el-footer